# Software Versioning Software

Tags: web-server, svn, version-control

I am looking for a small software versioning (changelog) and bug submission system with a web-frontend.
The features I only need is a change-log where users can see what they can expect and a tiny bug-submission system. I don't need the many features SVN offers as software versiong as the project is quite small and I do all development locally.

Answer (score 5):

The two classic web-based project management system with VCS integration and issue tracking are:

- [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) (based on Ruby)
- [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/)

Answer (score 3):

Independent the size of your project I think you can benefit from having a versioning system like SVN, you don't need to use all of its features just the ones you really need, also [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) is a very lightweight/interesting frontend/ticketing system that you can locally run.

Maybe this question can be better answered on Stack Overflow? Not sure.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at [fossil](http://fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki).

Comment: fossil rocks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I use Redmine a lot, but another possibility is just using plain [github](https://github.com/). It's free for open-source projects, and private repositories are also available for a fee. It has a very robust control system, incidences, and other things like wiki pages (also version-protected!). The only thing you need to set up is your local computer's ssh configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) or [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) are the software you need for the project management part.

Regarding the revision control softwares all the existing one have a lot of features, but some are quite easy to use.

I would advice [git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29), that for local development it's perfect. But take a look on [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software) to choose better (come back here if you are more confused then)

Comment: I have just moved from svn to git. I hear git works very well with trac, but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: @Matthew that's a good idea, much much more easier to use then SVN. Conisder it's the one used for the GNU/Linux kernel development ;-)

Answer (score 1):

[TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/) can be useful for your situation. I guess it needs to be changed a bit to match your needs.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

http://www.websvn.info/

This works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question - it made me realize something - Github has a bug submission system.

I don't mind reveling the source code of my projects so I host my version control off-site on http://github.com for free. Private repositories [cost $7 / 0.60GB / month](https://github.com/plans). They now host [1.5 million projects](http://ostatic.com/blog/at-year-end-open-sourcers-have-lots-to-celebrate).

It's very easy to use. I simply create an account and they [show me how to install and configure Git](http://help.github.com/creating-a-repo/) in place(s) where I will be developing from. In my opinion, Git is one of the few best and simplest version control systems out there.

I am familiar with command line so here is how my new projects are done:

```
# Create a new repository on Github
# Follow setup instructions

# cd into your new repository
cd myproject

# copy existing project files
cp -r ../project1/* .

# Commit all that's currently there
git add .
git commit

# Add new or modified files selectively
git add *.py
git status
git commit

# Add all modified files
git status
git commit -a

# Redo last commit
git commit -a --amend

# View log
git log

# Synchronize all the commits to the remote repository (GitHub)
git push

# Changes immediately show-up on Github
```